why not music to test stack exchange discussions?
Stackoverflow started a trial of a new feature: discussions.
I realized it wasn't tested on the music SE, I would think that music would be the best topic to test the discussions feature. Why wasn't this considered?
The question aims to focus on the actual reasons given for the decision (if music was even considered). This is not provoking a discussion, either you were involved with the process and have an answer or you weren't and don't.
These reasons could provide insight into creating discussions about music and help identifying topics to avoid.

This question seems to be in the middle of a conversation for which I don't know the beginning. In other words, what are we talking about here? Can you add some kind of preamble explaining the background of your question? Reasons given for what decision? Either involved in what process or not?

“Discussions feature”?

I can't find the discussions feature on the music stack exchange. you can find it on stackoverflow.com

there isn't a discussions feature on Music.SE

Your assumptions are incorrect. Within the SE ecosystem, there are the trilogy sites, and then everything else, which is tiny by comparison. Discussions is not yet even an option for smaller sites to look at - it is in SO Labs only.
When/if it becomes available for other sites, that would be a useful time to canvas opinion in here.

(In case anyone else didn't know, the ‘trilogy sites’ are apparently StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser — see this question.)

I find this question makes quite some rude assumptions here. What happened is that SO introduced a new beta feature two months ago, and music SE did not yet adopt it. You now start a question under the assumption that this means that current mods made an active decision to not use this feature. In fact, you first actual question is ”Why wasn’t this considered?“, which to me sounds a bit like ”It would have been your job to consider this, so why did you not do so?“.
Remember that this community is moderated by unpaid volunteers in their spare time. Maybe they are just not constantly up to date with each little beta feature SO pumps out, and maybe they have different things to do than considering for every beta feature whether we should be the ones testing is?
In my opinion it would be much more respectful and in the end useful to start a meta question: ”Hey, SO launched this new beta feature a while ago, which does ..., so maybe we could try to use this on music SE, as this seems like a feature quite well suited for this topic?“
Then people will be able to look it up, raise their points, and in the end make a decision.

I think the OP had less understanding of the SE ecosystem than that. I read it not as "why didn't you music folks adopt the discussions feature," but rather "why didn't it occur to whoever developed the discussions feature that music was a great use for it."
